# Access to the new Volumes and changing myself to admin

Tags: partitioning, permissions, administrator

I have a 1 TB HDD on my lenovo laptop which I manually configured for /boot, /var, /home, swap and root and was left with 876 GB which I divided into 2 volumes of 400+GB each - to use for my 'Workspace' and 'Personal' volumes.

However, whenever I login, I am only able to access and write to my /home but am unable to make any changes to Workspace and Personal volumes. Upon investigation, I find that the permissions on these are given to 'root' only. I tried to put an entry to the /etc/fstab with the UUID but it is of no use as these volumes are already mounted. It is just that I need to get access to these volumes.

Best would be to make my login as admin / su / super user. I did try to find how to do this but could not find the right solution (or maybe did not look in the right places). Many sites and solutions talk about the solutions of problems with dual boot esp. with windows. I have only Ubuntu on my machine and wish to keep it that way.

I need to bring almost 200 GB of data from my old laptop into this one and my /home is only 100 GB. I feel handcuffed. Can someone please help as I am not able to get on with my work.

**View of the Volumes**

[image: View of the Volumes]

**'Disks' View**

[image: 'Disks' View]

---

As suggested I tried to change the owner through chown however, my problem is not resolved. I even tried chown on /dev/sda3. Kindly see attached. Further, to my question, I am looking for a solution where I get full rights to these volumes as I boot and dont have to run the commands every time I restart the laptop.[snapshot of the terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/se8tV.png). Kindly help resolve this. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> However, whenever I login, I am only able to access and write to my /home but am unable to make any changes to Workspace and Personal volumes. Upon investigation, I find that the permissions on these are given to 'root' only. I tried to put an entry to the /etc/fstab with the UUID but it is of no use as these volumes are already mounted. It is just that I need to get access to these volumes.

Permissions for Unix-filesystems are not stored in `/etc/fstab`. They are part of the file system. To check the permissions of a particular folder, you can use `ls -l /path`.

To change the owner of a folder, you can use the command `chown`

```
sudo chown ${USER}:${USER} /media/vishnu/Workspace
```

This will make current user owner of that directory or file. ${USER} is a variable, set by bash when you log in, that expands to your username when interpreted by bash.

The default for a newly formatted Unix filesystem is that `root` owns the root of it, and this is what you're expiriencing.

You should *not* change ownership of system files, such as `/etc/`, `/usr/` and so forth, as this will Make Things Not Work(TM). Changing for arbitrary, user controlled directories are fine.

> Best would be to make my login as admin / su / super user. I did try to find how to do this but could not find the right solution (or maybe did not look in the right places). Many sites and solutions talk about the solutions of problems with dual boot esp. with windows. I have only Ubuntu on my machine and wish to keep it that way.

No, you don't find a right solution for it, because it is by definition not the right solution. There's almost zero reason to be logged in as super user in daily use. If you wish, you can set up Policy Kit (`pkexec`) and `sudo` to allow you to become root without prompting for authentication. But that still keeps a seperation of privileges, that you'll loose if you log in as root. Linux has a solid multiuser concept, and most tasks, including the one you seek to solve can be handled perfectly fine as a normal user.

As to your partioning; I would not spread your user data over multiple partitions. I see no reason not to have *all* the space you have on `/home`, and rather symlink it to other places, or even bind mount it, if needed. Splitting it simply makes management harder, as you risk running out of space in one partition, while having plenty free in another partition. This is, of course, my personal opinion.

Comment: Hi vidarlo Thanks for the help. However I checked the permissions using ls -l before and after running the 'chown' as directed by you. The permissions remain the same. drwx------ 2 root root 16384 Nov 12 15:11 lost+found. Also to cross check, I went into the files application and saw the permissions. Still no change. Not sure where I have gone wrong. Please help. Thanks.

Comment: You're seeing the permission of the `lost+found` directory. Leave that as is. After changing owner of the root of the partion, your user will be perfectly able to create files there.

Comment: Hi vidarlo, Thanks for the response. However, my issue is still not resolved. Please see below from my terminal. .../Workspace$ ls -l
total 16
drwx------ 2 root root 16384 Nov 12 15:11 lost+found
.../Workspace$ dir
lost+found
.../Workspace$ mkdir work
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘work’: Permission denied
.../Workspace$

Comment: Please edit your question to add new information. Comments are not meant for that. Also state the full commands you're running, including the `chown` command you ran.

Comment: Hi, I edited the question as suggested. The issue is still unresolved. Kindly see the snapshot of the commands I had run to gain access. Please help resolve. Thank you.

Comment: Why did you run `chown $root:$vishnu`? Run `sudo chown ${USER}:${USER} /media/vishnu/Workspace`. If you don't understand a command, it's better to ask for an explanation before you modify it.

Comment: Thanks a million. I tried it on Workspace and it works now. Can you tell me if I have to do this every time I restart my computer? If yes, is there any solution by which I get access to these volumes by default?

Comment: No, you don't have do it more than once. Please mark the answer as accepted if it solved your problem :)